# Is there any function in Codeigniter to find substring

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have searched a lot for this but I am unable to find that if there is any function like `substr()` in Codeigniter to find characters from starting till 6 letters of the string.
We can do this by core PHP function `substr($message,0,6)`, but is there some inbuit function like this in Codeigniter?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what are your reasons for wanting a built in CodeIgniter function just to use `substr`?

Comment: CodeIgniter is a PHP framework so if the whole framework is built with  PHP why would you want to have separate framework-internal function for such basic operation?

Comment: you can use php substr() then what is the need of CI function to get substring?

Comment: Frameworks should not re-implement basic language functions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why would you want a wrapper for substr when it is a core function?

The answer is no, use the function that comes with PHP.

https://www.php.net/substr

**Edit:** I stand corrected... There's something similiar built in to the 'text' library.

```
$string = "Here is a nice text string consisting of eleven words.";

$string = character_limiter($string, 20);

//Returns: Here is a nice text string…
```

This function will truncate the string at x amount of characters and add '...' as a suffix.

You obviously **haven't** 'searched a lot for this' because it's the top result when googling 'codeigniter substr'

Comment: I just wanted to know whether there is any function available.Thanks anyways.

Comment: "Thanks anyways". Doesn't this answer all your questions? :)

Comment: @Stanyer: i did searched but i didnt wanted `character_limiter`, I just wanted substring.

Comment: There is helper function in text library called characer_limiter http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/helpers/text_helper.html

Comment: @Nouphal.M I had already explained that

Answer (score 0):

This is important string function link http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/helpers/text_helper.html

You can use this function: $string = "Here is a nice text string consisting of eleven words.";

$string = character_limiter($string, 20);

Comment: It has been alreday mentioned by Stanyer